# Getting Z values when expecting a proper output

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Below is my code. It was supposed to output the addition of B+C when 'Odds' is true, and the subtraction of B-C when 'Evens' is true and 'Odds' is false. And then 0 when neither are true. I am getting ZZZ for the output of my full adder below - although all of the logic should be correct. I have checked multiple times...If you can help identify why my code is working that would be greatly appreciated.

```
module ECE228_2(
    input [7:0] A,
    input [3:0] B,
    input [3:0] C,
    output [4:0] Out
    );
    
    wire Odds, XEvens, Evens;
    wire [3:0]Bit4AddOut, Bit4AddCarry, Bit4SubOut, Bit4SubCarry, NotC;
    wire [4:0]EvenMuxOut;
    
    //C inversion for 2's Complement Subtraction
    not xC0(NotC[0],C[0]);
    not xC1(NotC[1],C[1]);
    not xC2(NotC[2],C[2]);
    not xC3(NotC[3],C[3]);
    
    //Generate The Xor of the Odd Positions to check for odd # of 1's
    xor xo0(Odds,A[1],A[3],A[5],A[7]);
    
    //Generate the Xor of the Even Positions and reverse it to check for even # of 1's
    xor xo1(XEvens,A[0],A[2],A[4],A[6]);
    not evenflip(Evens,XEvens);
    
    //4 Bit Add of B and C in case it is desired output
    FullAdd FA0(B[0],C[0],1'b0,Bit4AddOut[0],Bit4AddCarry[0]);
    FullAdd FA1(B[1],C[1],Bit4AddCarry[0],Bit4AddOut[1],Bit4AddCarry[1]);
    FullAdd FA2(B[2],C[2],Bit4AddCarry[1],Bit4AddOut[2],Bit4AddCarry[2]);
    FullAdd FA3(B[3],C[3],Bit4AddCarry[2],Bit4AddOut[3],Bit4AddCarry[3]);
    
    //4 Bit Subtract of B and C in case it is desired output
    FullAdd FAS0(B[0],NotC[0],1'b1,Bit4SubOut[0],Bit4SubCarry[0]);
    FullAdd FAS1(B[1],NotC[1],Bit4SubCarry[0],Bit4SubOut[1],Bit4SubCarry[1]);
    FullAdd FAS2(B[2],NotC[2],Bit4SubCarry[1],Bit4SubOut[2],Bit4SubCarry[2]);
    FullAdd FAS3(B[3],NotC[3],Bit4SubCarry[2],Bit4SubOut[3],Bit4SubCarry[3]);
    
    //2:1 Mux with even positions check as sel and (A-B) as true cases and 00000 as false case (5 Bits)
    MUX2_1 EvenMux0(Bit4SubOut[0],1'b0,Evens,EvenMuxOut[0]);
    MUX2_1 EvenMux1(Bit4SubOut[1],1'b0,Evens,EvenMuxOut[1]);
    MUX2_1 EvenMux2(Bit4SubOut[2],1'b0,Evens,EvenMuxOut[2]);
    MUX2_1 EvenMux3(Bit4SubOut[3],1'b0,Evens,EvenMuxOut[3]);
    MUX2_1 EvenMux4(Bit4SubCarry[3],1'b0,Evens,EvenMuxOut[4]);
    
    //2:1 Mux with odd positions check as sel and (A+B) as true case and even check as false case
    MUX2_1 OddMux0(Bit4AddOut[0],EvenMuxOut[0],Odds,Out[0]);
    MUX2_1 OddMux1(Bit4AddOut[1],EvenMuxOut[1],Odds,Out[1]);
    MUX2_1 OddMux2(Bit4AddOut[2],EvenMuxOut[2],Odds,Out[2]);
    MUX2_1 OddMux3(Bit4AddOut[3],EvenMuxOut[3],Odds,Out[3]);
    MUX2_1 OddMux4(Bit4AddCarry[3],EvenMuxOut[4],Odds,Out[4]);
    

       
endmodule


//Need a 2:1 MUX Module
module MUX2_1(
    input MuxTrue,
    input MuxFalse, 
    input MuxSel,   
    output MuxOut
    );

    wire MuxA1, MuxA2, XMuxSel;
    
    //Selector Not
    not XSel(XMuxSel,MuxSel);
    
    //When Sel is 1
    and MATrue(MuxA1,MuxTrue,MuxSel);
    
    //When Sel is 0
    and MAFalse(MuxA2,MuxFalse,XMuxSel);
    
    //Or of the cases
    or MuxOr(MuxOut,MuxA1,MuxA2);

endmodule

//Need a Full Adder Module
module FullAdd(
    input FAin1,
    input FAin2,
    input FACin,
    output FAOut,
    output FACout
    );
    
    wire FAWHA1Out,FAWHA1Cout,FAWHA2Cout;
    
    //Both calls to Half Adder
    HalfAdd FA_HA1(FAin1,FAin2,FAWHA1Cout,FAWHA1Out);
    HalfAdd FA_HA2(FAWHA1Out,FACin,FAWHA2Cout,FAout);
    or FAOr(FACout,FAWHA1Cout,FAWHA2Cout);
    
endmodule    

//Need a Half Adder Module
module HalfAdd(
    input HAin1,
    input HAin2,
    output HACout,
    output HAOut
    );
    
    //Gate design of a half adder
    //Add but output 0 for carryover condition
    xor HAXOR(HAOut,HAin1,HAin2);
    //check for carryover condition
    and HAAND(HACout,HAin1,HAin2);
    
endmodule
```

Here is the test bench:

```
module ECE228_2_test;
    reg [7:0]A;
    reg [3:0]B;
    reg [3:0]C;
    wire [4:0]Out;
   
ECE228_2 uut (
    .A(A),
    .B(B),
    .C(C),
    .Out(Out)
);    
    
initial
    begin
        B = 4'b0111;  //B = 7
        C = 4'b0011;  //C = 3         
        //Start counting
        A = 8'b00000000;
   #10   A = 8'b00000001; 
   #10   A = 8'b00000010;  
   #10   A = 8'b00000011; 
   #10   A = 8'b00000100; 
   #10   A = 8'b00000101; 
   #10   A = 8'b00000111; 
   #10   A = 8'b00001000;
        //Too many to count - Lets do some random instead   
   #10   A = 8'b11011000;
   #10   A = 8'b00011110;
   #10   A = 8'b10100101;
   #10   A = 8'b00110101;
   #10   A = 8'b11001010;
   #10   A = 8'b11100001;
   #10   A = 8'b11111111;
   #10   A = 8'b01011010;
   #10   A = 8'b01110010;
    end    
endmodule
```

Here is the output of the objects:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog is a case-sensitive language.  This means that the signal named `FAout` is different from the one named `FAOut`.

The `FullAdd` module output port, `FAOut`, is undriven, which means it will have the high-impedance value (`z`).  You likely meant to connect the output of the `FA_HA2` instance to the `FAOut` port instead of the signal named `FAout`.

Here is the fixed version of the module:

```
module FullAdd(
    input FAin1,
    input FAin2,
    input FACin,
    output FAOut,
    output FACout
    );
    
    wire FAWHA1Out,FAWHA1Cout,FAWHA2Cout;
    
    //Both calls to Half Adder
    HalfAdd FA_HA1(FAin1,FAin2,FAWHA1Cout,FAWHA1Out);
    HalfAdd FA_HA2(FAWHA1Out,FACin,FAWHA2Cout,FAOut);
    or FAOr(FACout,FAWHA1Cout,FAWHA2Cout);
    
endmodule
```

The full adder no longer has `z` output.

By default, Verilog does not require you to declare all signals.  You could also change the default behavior and require explicitly declared signals using this compiler directive:

```
`default_nettype none
```

This helps you find common coding mistakes like this.

```
Error-[IND] Identifier not declared
  Identifier 'FAout' has not been declared yet. If this error is not expected,
  please check if you have set `default_nettype to none.
```